# Ant Design Table - Page lags out when I try to edit a row

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using AntD table and I have allowed functionality to edit each row. I have over 8000 data for the table but when I try to edit a row, the page basically lags out. Initially I thought the problem is with the `editable-cell` component, because I have custom inputs for each column. But, after removing the custom inputs, it still lags out, so I think it most probably caused by the amount of data. Is there a way I can resolve this?

**ProductTable.jsx**

```js
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table, Typography, Form } from "antd";
import EditableCell from "./editable-cell";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "redux/hooks";
import actions from "redux/produk/actions";
import supplierActions from "redux/supplier/actions";

const ProdukTable = ({ originData }) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState(originData);
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");
  const [suppliers] = useAppSelector((state) => [state.supplier.suppliers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: supplierActions.GET_SUPPLIER,
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  const getSupplier = useCallback(
    (supplierId) => {
      const supplier = suppliers.find((x) => x.id === supplierId);
      return supplier ? supplier.name : supplierId;
    },
    [suppliers]
  );

  const merkProdukFilters = data
    .map((datum) => {
      return {
        text: datum.merk,
        value: datum.merk,
      };
    })
    .filter(
      (v, i, a) =>
        a.findIndex((v2) => ["text", "value"].every((k) => v2[k] === v[k])) ===
        i
    );

  const namaProdukFilters = data
    .map((datum) => {
      return {
        text: datum.name,
        value: datum.name,
      };
    })
    .filter(
      (v, i, a) =>
        a.findIndex((v2) => ["text", "value"].every((k) => v2[k] === v[k])) ===
        i
    );

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "ID Produk",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id",
    },
    {
      title: "Merk Produk",
      dataIndex: "merk",
      key: "merk",
      editable: true,
      filters: merkProdukFilters,
      filterSearch: true,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.merk.includes(value),
    },
    {
      title: "Nama Produk",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      editable: true,
      width: 450,
      filters: namaProdukFilters,
      filterSearch: true,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.startsWith(value),
    },
    {
      title: "Jenis Produk",
      dataIndex: "jenis",
      key: "jenis",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "Unit Satuan",
      dataIndex: "unit",
      key: "unit",
      editable: true,
      width: 90,
    },
    {
      title: "Kubikasi",
      dataIndex: "kubikasi",
      key: "kubikasi",
      editable: true,
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      title: "Berat / Volume",
      dataIndex: "volumeBerat",
      key: "volumeBerat",
      editable: true,
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      title: "Supplier",
      dataIndex: "supplierId",
      key: "supplierId",
      editable: true,
      width: 400,
      render: (_, record) => {
        if (!record.supplierId) return null;
        const formattedRecord = record.supplierId.map((id) => getSupplier(id));
        return formattedRecord.join(", ");
      },
    },
    {
      title: "Keterangan",
      dataIndex: "keterangan",
      key: "keterangan",
      editable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      fixed: "right",
      width: 70,
      render: (_, record) => {
        const editable = isEditing(record);
        return editable ? (
          <span>
            <Typography.Link
              onClick={() => save(record.key)}
              style={{
                marginRight: 8,
              }}
            >
              Save
            </Typography.Link>
            <Typography.Link onClick={cancel}>Cancel</Typography.Link>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <Typography.Link
            disabled={editingKey !== ""}
            onClick={() => edit(record)}
          >
            Edit
          </Typography.Link>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  function formatUndefined(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (i === "supplierId" && obj[i] === undefined) {
        obj[i] = [];
      }
      if (obj[i] === undefined) {
        obj[i] = "";
      }
    }

    return obj;
  }

  const isEditing = (record) => record.key === editingKey;
  const edit = (record) => {
    form.setFieldsValue({
      code: "",
      name: "",
      ...record,
    });
    setEditingKey(record.key);
  };
  const cancel = () => {
    setEditingKey("");
  };
  const save = async (key) => {
    try {
      const row = await form.validateFields();
      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);
      if (index > -1) {
        const item = newData[index];
        handleSaveChanges({
          ...item,
          ...formatUndefined(row),
        });
        newData.splice(index, 1, {
          ...item,
          ...row,
        });
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      } else {
        newData.push(row);
        setData(newData);
        setEditingKey("");
      }
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed:", errInfo);
    }
  };

  const mergedColumns = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.editable) {
      return col;
    }
    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record) => ({
        record,
        inputType: "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record),
      }),
    };
  });

  const handleSaveChanges = (newData) => {
    dispatch({
      type: actions.UPDATE_PRODUK,
      payload: {
        data: newData,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        }}
        bordered
        dataSource={data}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        rowClassName="editable-row"
        pagination={{
          onChange: cancel,
        }}
        rowKey="key"
        scroll={{
          x: 2000,
        }}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default ProdukTable;
```

**EditableCell.jsx**

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber, Select } from "antd";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "redux/hooks";
import { ITEM_UNITS } from "utils/constant";
import supplierActions from "redux/supplier/actions";

const EditableCell = ({
  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [jenisProduk, suppliers] = useAppSelector((state) => [
    state.produk.jenisProduk,
    state.supplier.suppliers,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: supplierActions.GET_SUPPLIER,
    });
  }, [dispatch]);

  const jenisProdukOptions = [
    {
      label: "Pilih Jenis Produk",
      value: "",
      disabled: true,
    },
    ...jenisProduk.map((jenis) => ({
      value: jenis.name,
      label: jenis.name,
    })),
  ];

  const unitsOptions = [
    {
      label: "Pilih Unit Produk",
      value: "",
      disabled: true,
    },
    ...ITEM_UNITS.map((unit) => ({
      value: unit,
      label: unit,
    })),
  ];

  const supplierOptions = suppliers.map((supplier) => ({
    value: supplier.id,
    label: supplier.name,
  }));

  const inputNode =
    dataIndex === "jenis" ? (
      <Select defaultValue={record.jenis} options={jenisProdukOptions} />
    ) : dataIndex === "unit" ? (
      <Select defaultValue={record.unit} options={unitsOptions} />
    ) : dataIndex === "kubikasi" ? (
      <Select
        defaultValue={record.kubikasi}
        options={[
          {
            label: "Pilih Kubikasi Produk",
            value: "",
            disabled: true,
          },
          {
            label: "Tonase",
            value: "tonase",
          },
          {
            label: "Volume",
            value: "volume",
          },
        ]}
      />
    ) : dataIndex === "supplierId" ? (
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        value={record.supplierId}
        options={supplierOptions}
      />
    ) : dataIndex === "volumeBerat" ? (
      <InputNumber
        step="0.000001"
        stringMode
        precision={6}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      />
    ) : (
      <Input />
    );
  return (
    <td {...restProps}>
      {editing ? (
        <Form.Item
          name={dataIndex}
          style={{
            margin: 0,
          }}
        >
          {inputNode}
        </Form.Item>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </td>
  );
};

export default EditableCell;
```

Comment: I surely would love to provide you with any info if needed.

Comment: Just write your code in the question. It will be difficult to identify the  problem.

Comment: I think loading 8000 records in dom is not good specially when table is editable. this doesn't mean it'll really solve the page lag issue. Handling state, avoiding expensive operations are also important when it comes to large amount of data. Try virtual list like [Antd Virtualist](https://github.com/crawler-django/virtuallist-antd) or any other package.

Comment: @Owen Please use React.memo for each row with individual input. Let me know if you need details analysis on this.

Comment: @sushildlh Do you have an example of this? I have 0 experience with memos.

Comment: look this https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely and use it your input components. I think ANTD is using this internally in their table.